# Can we have an "x many members logged on" box?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Sometimes when I ask a question and no one has even viewed my question, I wonder how many people are actually on here. Can we have an "x many members logged on" box? As an added bonus, this would also convince others that this is the place to ask their Christianity questions because it has so many users.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is completely unnecessary and generally isn't in line with the mission of Stack Exchange.

If you want to interact with users live, that's what chat is for.

However, knowing *how many* folks are online would be irrelevant to your ability to get answers for two reasons. First and foremost, a lot of folks have tag subscriptions or RSS feeds that tell them when questions come through for tags they are interested in, so they wouldn't show up as present even if they are interested in answering questions. But second, because we don't *care* generally *how quickly* a question is answered. If it gets answered within a day or two, that's great. However, the *best* questions take time to answer, and especially to be answered thoroughly.

There are two kinds of really good questions here. The first is the one that we already have an expert for. These are good, and are well served. However, one of the *best* types of questions is the one for which *we don't have an expert yet*. That way, when that expert *is* poking around the internet, or lands on the site, they *immediately* can find things that they can answer and contribute to.

Most importantly. This isn't a forum, it's a Q&A site, users generally don't *hang out* here looking for interaction, they ask/answer questions here. As such, a feature telling you how many people are "logged in" probably isn't very useful for this type of application.